# java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!(I went to couchbase to query the data.)

Tags: java, couchbase

I have so many object fields (over 3000) that I go to couchbase database to query data for exceptions (Method code too large!).Before, when I used Spring, the same time this object can be query and normal use, but in SpringBoot is not possible(exception image), I changed to a smaller object, this query is normal

```
//My Run Code:
MyObjectRepository.findOne("id");
```

```
MyObjectRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<MyObject,String>
```

Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!

    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.createAccessorClass(ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.java:183)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.potentiallyCreateAndRegisterPersistentPropertyAccessorClass(ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.java:167)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.getPropertyAccessor(ClassGeneratingPropertyAccessorFactory.java:80)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.getPropertyAccessor(BasicPersistentEntity.java:425)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.getPropertyAccessor(CouchbaseTemplate.java:706)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.doPersist(CouchbaseTemplate.java:576)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.save(CouchbaseTemplate.java:233)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.save(CouchbaseTemplate.java:228)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.support.SimpleCouchbaseRepository.save(SimpleCouchbaseRepository.java:86)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:520)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:505)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:477)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.support.ViewPostProcessor$ViewInterceptor.invoke(ViewPostProcessor.java:87)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.save(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.save(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Why on earth would you need 3000+ fields?

Comment: project needs it. I can't help it

Comment: Well, it's generating too large methods, so you're going to have to help it (or find a way to generate a smaller method, but that basically means less fields in the object).

Comment: I tried to split the object, using  with successive extends small object, but I also reported the error later

Comment: You shouldn't use extension (where the child class has all the fields of the parent class+itself) but rather composition (where a root class has references to different instances of classes that hold parts of the fields)

Comment: But I need to do this in my project, using the properties of this object directly

Comment: @PerryQiu then you should go through the documentation for Couchbase and Spring to see if you can affect the generation of the accessors. If you could disable it (or tune it somehow), it wouldn't try to create a too big method. It would probably result in some minor performance hit though.

Comment: Have you considered using a Map instead of an object with fields?